# Cancelar que redireccione a una página desde javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo un formulario con un botón de login y al presionar el botón me da una alerta de JavaScript que dice si quiero confirmar o no.

Mi pregunta es: ¿cómo hago para que al presionar cancelar me deje en la página del formulario?

Aquí está el código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function confirmDemo(){
            //Ingresamos un mensaje a mostrar
        var mensaje = confirm("Estas seguro que quieres enviar el registro?");
        //Detectamos si el usuario acepto el mensaje
        if (mensaje){
            alert("El registro fue enviado");  
        }  
        //detectamos si el usuario denegó el mensaje
        else{
            alert("Haz cancelado el envío del registro");
        }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Y ahora cuando le das a cancelar que sucede?

Comment: Falta el código html donde llamas a esa función. Asi no podemos saber si lo que te falta es  e.preventDefault(); o si es mejor que hagas el form.submit(); en caso correcto. Si hay un form con un botón, tambien puedes probar a cambiar el type="submit" por type="button". Pero solo con este código ...

Answer (score 2):

Depende de cómo invoques esa función el método podría ser uno u otro.

### Desde `onsubmit` (no recomendado)

En ese caso debes propagar con `return` si quieres enviar o no el formulario de la siguiente manera:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function confirmDemo() {
    // Ingresamos un mensaje a mostrar
    let mensaje = confirm("Estas seguro que quieres enviar el registro?");
    // Detectamos si el usuario aceptó el mensaje
    if (mensaje) {
      alert("El registro fue enviado");  
    } else {
      // el usuario denegó el mensaje
      alert("Has cancelado el envío del registro");
    }
    return mensaje;
  }
</script>

<form onsubmit="return confirmDemo();" id="formulario">
  <input type="text" name="nombre" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Lo importante en este código es que un `return true` en el atributo `onsubmit` permite el envío del formulario y un `return false` lo cancela, por lo que la función debe devolver si se canceló o no el envío para que se termine enviando o no el formulario.

### Evento `submit` (recomendado)

En caso de haber configurado el evento `submit` del formulario entonces debes cancelar la ejecución del comportamiento por defecto con [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault):

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function confirmDemo(evento) {
    // Ingresamos un mensaje a mostrar
    let mensaje = confirm("Estas seguro que quieres enviar el registro?");
    // Detectamos si el usuario aceptó el mensaje
    if (mensaje) {
      alert("El registro fue enviado");  
    } else {
      // el usuario denegó el mensaje
      alert("Has cancelado el envío del registro");
      /* Evitamos el comportamiento por defecto (enviar el formulario) */
      evento.preventDefault();
    }
    return mensaje;
  }
</script>

<form id="formulario">
  <input type="text" name="nombre" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>

<script>
  /* Agregamos el manipulador de eventos */
  formulario.addEventListener('submit', confirmDemo);
</script>
```

Como has podido ver se requiere el parámetro de la función `evento` para poder cancelar el comportamiento por defecto del manipulador de eventos cuando se envía el formulario.